# how to save entry box in dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i have create automatic entry box

but values print dictionary

example {["ent1":'computer',"ent2": '1800'], ["ent1":'laptop', "ent2":'2000'], ["ent1":'mouse',"ent2": '500']}

```
from tkinter import *

class sample:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        self.all_entries = list()

        showButton = Button(root, text='Show all text',command= self.showEntries)
        showButton.pack()

        addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red", command=self.addBox)
        addboxButton.pack()

    def addBox(self):
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.ent1 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.ent2 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.all_entries.append([self.ent1,self.ent2])

    def showEntries(self):

        values = [[entry.get() for entry in entry_set] for entry_set in self.all_entries]
        print(values)

root = Tk()
obj = sample(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is `{["ent1":'computer',"ent2": '1800'], ["ent1":'laptop', "ent2":'2000'], ["ent1":'mouse',"ent2": '500']}` your expected output, or is it the output the program is currently giving? Either way, it's doubly incorrect Python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print in list of dictionary, change

```py
values = [[entry.get() for entry in entry_set] for entry_set in self.all_entries]
```

to

```py
values = [{f"ent{i}":entry.get() for i,entry in enumerate(entry_set,1)} for entry_set in self.all_entries]
```

---

The output of `print(values)` will be something like:

```py
[{'ent1': 'value1', 'ent2': 'value2'}, {'ent1': 'hello', 'ent2': 'world'}]
```